# Custom routes never matched in Sitecore request execution

Tags: pipelines, custom-route

I followed the steps below to define custom ASP.NET MVC routes.

Created a custom processor for the initialize pipeline and defined custom route in the Process method similar to the following:

```
public class RegisterCustomRoute
{
  public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
  {
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "some/route/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
  }
}
```

Added this processor to the initialize pipeline right before the Sitecore `InitializeRoutes` processor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
     <sitecore>
          <pipelines>
               <initialize>
                    <processor type="MyNamespace.RegisterCustomRoute, MyAssembly" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
               </initialize>
          </pipelines>
     </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I placed this patch file into a subfolder of the `/App_Config/Include/Z_CustomConfigs` directory.

The route has been registered successfully in the `RouteTable` however whenever i tried to access the url `http://[domain]/some/route/[controller]/[action]/1` in browser, I never get this url matched in Sitecore application and it always redirected to 404 page with invalid url message.

**Update**

I am having below code for the controller

```
public class ProductFilterController : SitecoreController
{
     // GET: Product
     public ActionResult Search(int id)
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

And trying to access it using the url

```
http://mydomain.com/some/route/ProductFilter/Search/1
```

However, when i added `/some/route/` in `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` config setting, the route resolved successfully but in this way, i would not get the Sitecore context. Thus, not much beneficial to resolve the problem statement.

References: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/700677

Comment: We would need to see the actual code and actual configuration, to be able to help you.

Comment: I tried the exact same code and configuration but it never worked.

Comment: But your controller code?

Comment: To narrow down your issue, do you mind moving the custom route definition to your Global.asax's Session_Start method for example: if (RouteTable.Routes["CustomRoute"] == null)
   {
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "some/route/{controller}/{action}");
   }

Comment: Don't inherit SitecoreController. It isn't intended for this purpose. It would be either ServicesApiController or just ApiController. And don't modify global.asax either.

Comment: I tried, but this also doesn't work.

Comment: Also consider https://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/

Comment: In case of `ServicesApiController` (ASP.NET WebAPI) there is even no need of overriding the processor (which is for MVC routing). See the following page for details: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/use_the_restful_api_for_the_entityservice